# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. my sql server store procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please, can anyone help me out how to rewrite the following query not to the above   error.

```
    `select    distinct(at.RoomNumber),at.RoomID,'','','','','','',at.CheckInDate,at.CheckOutDate  from AvailableTest at                       
    join Room r on r.RoomID = at.RoomID 
    join Reservations res on res.RoomID =r.RoomID where
                        at.CheckInDate not in(select roomid,CheckInDate,checkoutdate,RoomCurrentStatus
                         from reservations rs  where ((CheckInDate between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                         or  (CheckOutDate  between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and  '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM'))) and exists (select roomid,CheckInDate    ,checkoutdate,RoomCurrentStatus
                         from AvailableTest avt  where ((CheckInDate between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                         or  (CheckOutDate  between '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' and   '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')) )`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you specify 'CheckInDate not in...' you then have a subquery with multiple fields, you can only compare CheckInDate against one field, try the below

```
SELECT DISTINCT (at.RoomNumber), at.RoomID, '', '', '', '', '', '', at.CheckInDate, at.CheckOutDate
FROM AvailableTest at
INNER JOIN Room r
    ON r.RoomID = at.RoomID
INNER JOIN Reservations res
    ON res.RoomID = r.RoomID
WHERE at.CheckInDate NOT IN (
        SELECT  CheckInDate
        FROM reservations rs
        WHERE (
                (CheckInDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                OR (CheckOutDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                )
        )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT roomid, CheckInDate, checkoutdate, RoomCurrentStatus
        FROM AvailableTest avt
        WHERE (
                (CheckInDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                OR (CheckOutDate BETWEEN '07/18/2014 13:00:00 PM' AND '07/24/2014 12:00:00 AM')
                )
        )
```